# restore db postgres - format .gz

Tags: postgresql, gzip

I am trying to restore a database on my local machine. I downloaded this database from the server in file.gz format. Inside this archive is the file file.out. How can I restore the entire structure on my computer through
pg_admin or via console?

If I understand correctly, you need to use the pg_restore command. But all my attempts end with a syntax error.

Comment: What is inside the file `file.out`? (There are several kinds of database dumps.)

Comment: 1) Add the complete command you used to do the restore, as text, to your question. 2) Add the content of the syntax error as text to your question.